# How do I test sending emails using SMTP and OAuth2? Is there a free server/service for that?

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, smtp

My code sends emails using SMTP and OAuth2.

How do I test it?

Is there a free server/service for that?

Comment: If you found a solution yet, please let us know - this thread will probably become a lot more relevant as MS is switching Exchange Online to OAuth2 currently.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same thing. I did not want to have to bother our IT admins by using our company email server.

Microsoft is now offering a FREE developer sandbox that allows you to setup a whole range of environments - including Active Directory and Office 365.
It is good for 90 days or longer - as long as you are actively using it.
If you have a Microsoft developer subscription like Visual Studio or the old MSDN subscriptions - use that option when registering (it's not obvious) and your sandbox will auto-renew as long as you maintain that subscription - if you are using the sandbox or not.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365

Please note: The MS Dev365 environment is ONLY GOOD for testing Microsoft OAuth. Apparently OAuth2 is very implementation dependent - there does not seem to be a one-size-works-for-all way to implement OAuth2.